# Inconsistency between result of space used(data field) by table, returned by sp_spaceused and space after data exported to csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm exporting the data from SQL Server to flat file(csv).
But I saw inconsistency between result of space used(data field of result) by table returned by `sp_spaceused` and space after data exported to csv.

eg. `sp_spaceused` is showing used space by table 2Gb
But after exporting to csv file it is taking 7GB.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: The space used in a table and the space occupied by a CSV are not very closely related.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: @ADITYAPAWAR I believe it is YOU that needs to elaborate. Show your work. It seems you compare the size of a text file with the space consumed within the database of that same information - is that correct? Generally speaking, any non-string (i.e., char and related) dataypes will store information more compactly than storing that same information as a string. And your files has "extra" characters like spaces, field separators, line separators, etc.

Comment: Yes you are correct i'm comparing the size of a text file with the space consumed within the database of that same information. For other things like field separators the space will be used,i agree. But the difference I'm seeing is huge. As I mentioned 2GB in DB but 7GB for extracted file. Also one more tabel shows 8GB in DB but actually taking 26 GB after extraction. So I wanted to know why so much difference. I need this because I'm splitting my table based on size into multiple extract files.

Comment: Unless you edit your question to include your table schema we can only say "yes, this happens sometimes" and move on. To elaborate on SMor's comment with a specific example: the `uniqueidentifier` type is stored in 16 bytes inside SQL tables but when written to an ANSI/UTF-8 file consumes 36 characters and when written to a Widechar/UTF-16 file consumes 72 bytes. SQL types often consume more space in text files than they do in tables because they have to be converted to strings to be stored in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are reasons why the CSV might be larger:

- The commas and newlines have no equivalent in the database representation.
- A 4-byte integer value occupies 4 bytes in the database, but could be up to 11 characters in the file (-1,000,000,000 for instance).
- String might be saved using wide character sets but stored as single bytes.
- `date`s occupy 3 bytes in the database but probably 10 characters (YYYY-MM-DD) in the result set.
- `datetime`s occupy 8 bytes in the database but 19-23 characters in the result set.

There are no doubt other examples.

The size can also be smaller.  The database has overhead that is not in a CSV file:

- Used space on pages.
- Null flags.
- Small numbers.  "1" only occupies one character in the CSV but 4 bytes in the data.

And no doubt other examples.